# Xcode 11.0 simulator swiping gestures do not work

Tags: ios-simulator, gesture, xcode11

After Xcode update to version 11.0 the swiping gestures in the simulator do not work. Is it a bug? Have you the same experience?

Thanx for helping.

Comment: I have the same experience. On iOS 13.0 simulator gestures do not work, yet on 12.2 and 10.3.1 they do. Probably usual buggy release of the Xcode

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and what resolved it for me was switching the presentation of the view controller from automatic to full screen.